# How can I access the Header information from a HTTP Post in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http-headers

I am developing a MVC Web Application and I need to find a way to access the Header information of a HTTP Post that is being invoked from another application/source. So alls that i want my application to do is listen for a HTTP Post on a specific view and then pull the information from its Header, any ideas???

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Request.Headers` which will give you everything the client has submitted:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.headers.aspx

Answer (score 4):

In your controller use Request.Headers.